# Which online APIs return elevation data without the height of trees and buildings?

Tags: dem, elevation, api

I work on applications that generate topographic maps and analyze GPS tracks. My main concern is the presence of "bumps" due to the height of trees and buildings returned by the elevation APIs.

The best results I've had so far are with the [TessaDEM Elevation API](https://tessadem.com/elevation-api/) which has a 30-meter resolution and removes tree height. Do you know if there is another API that might provide better resolution or might better remove the height of buildings?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Global DSM and DTM data via website or API is provided by NEXTMap Elevation Data Suite see their web site for details ~ https://www.intermap.com/nextmap